# how to stop auto generate class comments vscode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I remember there was a setting in VScode to stop these comments from generating.

```
/**
 * @description       : 
 * @author            : username
 * @group             : 
 * @last modified on  : 02-08-2023
 * @last modified by  : username
**/
```

[image]

I tired to diable Current Line Blame but it did not work for me.

Comment: What relevant extensions do you have enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce Documenter VScode extension was causing the comments.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HugoOM.sfdx-autoheader

fixed by disabling SFDoc.EnableForApex extension settings

Comment: _What_ extension? Give the id of the extension and ideally a link to its page on the Visual Studio Marketplace. _How_ was it causing them? Is it changeable by a setting? Is it only triggered by a certain action like using a snippet?

Comment: much better. You should hold yourself to at _least_ this standard of quality when writing answers in the future.